# Differential equation, perturbation method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the one dimensional ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=\epsilon y^2 +x$, where $y=y(x,\epsilon)$.

Discuss the effect of changes in the values of parameter $\epsilon$ in the solution
(hint: assume initially $\epsilon_{0} =0$ and initial condition $y(0,0)=0$, then see how different $y(x,0)$ is from the $y(x,\epsilon)$.

I first tried to solve the ODE, but I couldn't. How can I apply the perturbation method here?

Comment: When you say $y(0) = 0$, do you mean $y(0,0) = 0$ or $y(x,0) = 0$?

Comment: In other word , is it necessary to solve the  D equation?

Comment: Thnk you Stahl for your comment, I mean y (0,0)=0

Comment: Are you asked to prove that $y_0(x)=\frac12x^2$ and, for every $\epsilon\gt0$, $y_\epsilon(x)\gt y_0(x)$ for $x\gt0$ and $y_\epsilon(x)\lt y_0(x)$ for $x\lt0$?

Answer (score 6):

We start by expanding $y$ in powers of $\epsilon$, i.e.

$$ y(x;\epsilon) = y_{0}(x) + \epsilon y_{1}(x) + \epsilon^{2}y_{2}(x) + \ldots $$

Substitute this expansion into our differential equation:

$$ y_{0}' + \epsilon y_{1}' + \ldots = \epsilon\left(y_{0} + \epsilon y_{1} + \ldots \right)^{2} + x .$$

Now collect terms in increasing powers of epsilon and solve the resulting equations. Start with the $\epsilon^{0}$ equation.

$$\epsilon^{0}: y_{0}' = x$$
$$\implies y_{0} = \frac{1}{2}x^{2} + C_{0}$$
Apply the initial condition:
$$y(0) = 0 \implies C_{0} = 0.$$
Now solve the $\epsilon^{1}$ equation.
$$\epsilon^{1}:  y_{1}' = (y_{0})^{2}$$

$$y_{1}' = \frac{1}{4}x^{4}$$
$$\implies y_{1} = \frac{1}{20}x^{5} + C_{1}$$
Again, we apply the initial condition to see that $C_{1} = 0$.

Thus

$$y(x;\epsilon) = \frac{1}{2}x^{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{20}x^{5} + \text{higher order terms}.$$

(If you want to find the higher order terms you will have to substitute in and solve the $\epsilon^{2}$ equation, then the $\epsilon^{3}$ equation and so on, in a similar fashion as above.)